# Points in shifted with different projected coordinate systems in same map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, united-states

I am trying to map points on top of a map of Michigan taken from eBird a citizen science platform that records where birds were sighted. I downloaded an excel file for ebird sighting points, to use in ArcMap. eBird points are recorded through the WGS 84 datum, but my map of Michigan is on the Projected Coordinate System NAD_1983_Michigan_GeoRef_Meters. When I add the eBird data and it defaults to the NAD 83 coordinate system the points appear about 45 degrees southwest of where they should be in Illinois/Iowa instead of northern Michigan. When I use the Define Projection and Projection tool to set it at WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere the points appear in the same place.

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The excel data you have is in WGS 1984, which is a Geographic coordinate system, so the values of X and Y must be in decimal degree or degree minutes seconds.

The map is in a projected coordinate system (Meters), so even if you define the projection of your excel data to PCS, the map does not fall in the right place.

What you should do is either change the values in excel to meters, which is a time-consuming process, try changing the map projection to WGS 1984.

Comment: Or when you use the Define Projection tool, set it to 4326 aka geographic coordinate systems - world . WGS 1984